# Does ANTLR4 support assigning a literal name to a token?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Let's say you have grammar with a case-insensitive `foo` token defined like this:

```
FOO : F O O ;

fragment F:('f'|'F');
fragment O:('o'|'O');
```

For this token [Vocabulary.getLiteralName(token)](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Vocabulary.html#getLiteralName(int)) returns `null` since it was defined by matching a pattern and not a literal value.

Does Antlr4 have a built-in way to specify a literal value for the `foo` token in the grammer definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a toString() method in almost every ANTLR4 runtime class. For hierarchical elements like (parse)trees and recognition contexts the child entries are listed in the toString() output, but usully with some form of formatting (like commad separated lists).

So, the answer is: no. There is no built-in way to get the text of a subtree as a single unformatted string. Writing a concatenation function is however trivial. Simply create a function getText(RuleContext context) that returns a string and which iterates over the children of the context and calls getText() (or uses the vocabulary) on each of them and then returns a concatenated string from the values.

Comment: Thank you. I'm more concerned about individual tokens than subtrees, but that's good to know!

Comment: Well, even lexer tokens can contain subtrees. After all a single node is a subtree as well (just with no children).

Answer (score 1):

`getSymbolicName(int)` should return `FOO` for the input `"foo"`:

```
TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("foo"));

for (Token token : lexer.getAllTokens()) {
  System.out.println(TLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(token.getType()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's the technique I've been using, deriving the literal name from the symbolic name according to a certain convention. But for tokens that deviate from the convention, special handling is required. I was hoping to eliminate the need for special handling in my code.

Comment: "But for tokens that deviate from the convention, special handling is required." - just curious, in which cases does `getSymbolicName(...)` not give the expected result?

Comment: `getSymbolicName` always behaves correctly; I'm just trying to decouple the token name from the literal name. The convention I've been using is to convert `UPPER_UNDERSCORE` to `dot.separated.lowercase`. Now I'm flirting with the idea of having some tokens where the literal value contains whitespace, and I'd rather not say something like "two underscores in a row means use a space instead of a dot".

Comment: Ah, ok , I see.